# java.lang.VerifyError: class org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty3Plugin overrides final method onModule

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch

I am trying to create an ElasticSearch TransportClient using ElasticSearch 5.4.0. The client is created as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unchecked" })
private static Client getTransportClient() {

    try {
        InetSocketTransportAddress inetAddress = new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300);
        client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY).addTransportAddress(inetAddress);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage());
    }

    return client;
}
```

Now, when running, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty3Plugin overrides final method onModule.(Lorg/elasticsearch/common/network/NetworkModule;)V
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<clinit>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:54)
at org.personal.elastic.twitter.ElasticUtil.getTransportClient(ElasticUtil.java:65)
at org.personal.elastic.twitter.ElasticUtil.indexTweet(ElasticUtil.java:42)
at org.personal.elastic.twitter.TweetHunter.main(TweetHunter.java:39)
```

By the look of the error, it seems like some dependency conflict issue (Netty3Plugin?). In that regard, I would like to provide a snippet from my pom.xml for the ElasticSearch and Transport client dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

Please let me know, what could be wrong (either with my maven dependencies or API usage)? I may try to go back use older version of ElasticSearch (2.x, maybe?), but, I don't want to... Help is appreciated!

Comment: You probably have an incompatible version of the transitive dependency (netty?). You may need to explicitly exclude it from other dependencies. Check the dependency tree and you may spot where the wrong version is coming from.

Comment: Thanks @ErnestKiwele, upon investigation I found out that there was a deprecated overriden final method `onModule()` in Netty3Plugin.java. Using the latest version(5.4.0, instead of 5.0.0-beta1) of `transport` plugin, from where Netty3Plugin is coming, resolved the issue.